# How to crop sides on carousel image in Bootstrap-3? Not resize horizontal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, responsiveness

I'm using Bootstrap's sample 'carousel.css and html' Using an image size 1500x500

How can I maintain the height of the image and, without distorting the image, crop an equal amount off of each side if the browser window becomes smaller than the image, leaving the height at 500px?

This is the related CSS that Bootstrap provides and I'm using.

```
.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="first-slide" src="images/1600x500.png" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Heading</h1>
          <p>Text text text.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn More</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you in advance. I've scoured this forum as well as others and can't seem to crack this.  As simple as it sounds.

Comment: please add your html

Comment: I've edited your question to hopefully clarify what you're looking for, please @ping me if I've deviated from your original intent. Also, please include all relevant code necessary to reproduce the issue. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: And, have you tried using a background image and `background-size: contain`?

Comment: This is a foreground image, as indicated above.  I can't use background in this case.